# How to make <div> active on page load using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

On page load, I want to show #tab-2 active and show the content under tab-2. How to use jQuery to do that. I tried `$('div > ul > li > a, #tabs-2').show();` but this did not work.

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1"></a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2"></a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3"></a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-4"></a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tabs-1">
"short" content
</div>

<div id="tabs-2">
"long" content
</div>

<div id="tabs-3">
"long" content
</div>

<div id="tabs-4">
"long" content
</div>
```

[Link to demo](http://jsbin.com/ovacez/5) - Show Tab 2 active onload but this is how it looks

Thanks @Jack for the quick and correct response

Comment: What do you mean by not work? Something should happen, unless you're trying to use jQuery before the elements are ready.

Comment: Have you checked this --> http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

Comment: This is how it looks on load --> http://jsbin.com/ovacez/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demo shows that you are using JQuery UI's Tabs.

When you initialize tabs, you can specify which tab is active by default, like so:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ active: 1 });
```

`1` is the second tab because the tab indices start with `0`.

For this to work, you will need to remove the `$('#tabs-2, a[href="#tabs-2"]').show();` code.

Comment: Thanks!!, Really appreciate your response.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show both the anchor *and* `<div>` element:

```
$('#tabs-2, a[href="#tabs-2"]').show();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ovacez/1/)

**Update**

If you're using the tabs widget, you should do this instead:

```
$( "#tabs" )
    .tabs({active: 1});
```

That selects the second tab and opens it.

Comment: The problem I am facing is when I do what you have suggested or what I did earlier is that, I see the content of Tab-2 under Tab-1 and Tab-1 is selected. I have made the script run after all the elements are created.

Comment: @java_dude I'm not sure what you mean by that; have you looked at the demo link I've added? Perhaps you could make some changes to it and then tell me the updated link so that I can see what's going on. It's hard to tell from what you have told me so far.

Comment: @java_dude Oh, you just need `{active: 1}` in the `.tabs()` call to select the second tab by default.

Comment: @Jack.. Wondering if you would like to work on a side project as consultant

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to fire it when the elements are loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   });
```

You can also use jquery **fadeIn/fadeOut**

Comment: I was using this instead --> $(function() { ... }

Answer (score 0):

did you hide another tabs before showing ?

you can use this

## tabs-1, #tabs-2, #tabs-3, #tabs-4 { display:none }

Comment: Not hiding any tabs. Just when the page loads I want to show tabs-2

Answer (score 0):

Give all the elements you want to show together same class value then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.classvalue').show();
});
```